# Can't login after suspend

Tags: login, login-screen

I can't login to my account after GNOME suspend. I'm typing password correct, but it shows "Incorrect password". I must click Power Off the computer. I'm using Ubuntu 20.10.

Did anyone experience this problem?

How can I fix it?

Comment: There's a post already related to this issue. Here is possible [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968275/cant-login-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-17-10)